# Ruby: what is the pitfall in this simple code excerpt that tests variable existence

Tags: ruby, variables, ruby-1.9

I'm starting with Ruby, and while making some test samples, I've stumbled against an error in the code that I don't understand why it happens.

The code pretends to tests if a variable finn is defined?() and if it is defined, then it increments it. If it isn't defined, then it will define it with value 0 (zero).
As the code threw an error, I started to decompose it in small pieces and run it, to better trace where the error was comming from.
The code was run in IRB irb 0.9.5(05/04/13), using ruby 1.9.1p378

First I certify that the variable finn is not yet defined, and all is ok:

```
?> finn
NameError: undefined local variable or method `finn' for main:Object
        from (irb):134
        from /home/paulo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/irb:15:in `<main>'
>>
```

Then I certify that the following inline-condition executes as expected, and all is ok:

```
?> ((defined?(finn)) ? (finn+1):(0))
=> 0
```

And now comes the code that throws the error:

```
?> finn=((defined?(finn)) ? (finn+1):(0))
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):143
        from /home/paulo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/irb:15:in `<main>'
```

I was expecting that the code would not throw any error, and that after executing the variable finn would be defined with a first value of 0 (zero). But instead, the code thows the error, and finn get defined but with a value of nil.

```
>> finn
=> nil
```

Where might the error come from?!? Why does the inline-condition work alone, but not when used for the finn assignment?

Any help apreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line,

```
finn=((defined?(finn)) ? (finn+1):(0))
```

When you write `finn=`, it declares finn, and sets it to nil until the assignment occurs. Therefore, `defined?(finn)` returns `true` , so it attempts to execute `finn+1`, which is equivalent to `nil+1`, which results in the NoMethodError you mentioned above.

You may be looking for this:

```
finn ||= 0
finn += 1
```

Comment: ok - thanks for the explanation
How would you recomend to do it instead? There must be a more "rubyesq" way to do it...

Comment: rubii's way is The Ruby Way(tm). Mine is a cheap facsimile ;)

Comment: Yours and @rubiii's answer can be combined, sort of: `finn = (finn || 0) + 1`

Answer (score 1):

john is right. try:

```
finn = finn ? finn + 1 : 0
```